# How do I deploy a console-ran web socket server to Azure?

Tags: azure, wcf, websocket, console

I have an .NET console application that spins up a web socket server in the form of a WCF service. The service is primarily consumed by an in-browser JS client. I'd like to deploy this to Azure, and I have tried deploying to a Web App and as a Webjob. These haven't worked and I don't believe they are the right option as my understanding is they can only listen on ports 80 and 443, and run w3wp.exe.

So what kind of resource do I need to provision in Azure to deploy and run this app?

Implementation details:

WCF config:

```
<services>
  <service name="WebSocketService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>            
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>        
    <endpoint address="CallbackService" binding="customBinding" contract="IWebSocketService" bindingConfiguration="webSocket" />                
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="webSocket">
      <byteStreamMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport>
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" createNotificationOnConnection="true" />
      </httpTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Program.cs:

```
var svcInstance = container.Resolve<IWebSocketService>();
var svcHost = new ServiceHost(svcInstance);            
svcHost.Open();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: My first guess would be to have it run in a [VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) or on a [Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using SignalR and in particulr the Azure SignalR Service - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview